# How to redirect to a different URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

My site url is `www.testing.com` and there is another site `www.testing.com/newsite`.

I want everyone who hits `www.testing.com/newsite` to be redirected to `www.newsite.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write header like:

```
  header("Location: http://www.testing.com");
```

on the home page of http://www.testing.com/newsite

for more about [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: Can it is possible by htaccess ?

Comment: @PiyushKumar use the unamata sanatarai's solution for using htaccess

Answer (score 5):

So simply add below line at index page.

```
header("Location: http://www.testing.com", false, 301);
exit;
```

Or write it in common file that are included in every page.

make sure there is `http://` in header location other wise it will look for directory.

And also put `exit;` at the end so other code will not execute.

because sending header will not terminate script execution.

--EDIT--
it should be 301 to make it last forever

Comment: Disadvantage of this is that you need to make an index file in the newsite folder. A better way is to use .htaccess and redirect it from there.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a directory `/newsite` then place a `.htaccess` inside that directory with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.newsite.com/ [R=301,L]
```

**However** if you directed the `newsite.com` into the `/newsite` directory, then you need what [Sankalp Mishra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15430790/2119863) wrote in his answer. (but with *newsite* instead of *testing*)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^newsite$ http://www.newsite.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks , I want to redirect it on www.newsite.com so I should write it as RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.newsite.com/ [R=301,L]

Comment: you're right, thanks for the correction!

Comment: Ok I just want to confirm , If some one directly hit www.newsite.com , then this will not create the problem like redirect multiple times to same domain.

Comment: **IFF** you place it inside the `/newsite` directory

Answer (score 0):

Use this in htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^newsite.*$ http://www.testing.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: why use the .* in the expression?